# Cassandra N copies in N cluster?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cluster-computing

I'm trying to configure Cassandra cluster on EC2.
The thing is that (for my purposes) I want to have N replicas in N machine cluster (all machine should have the same data).

I did the following:
- made a N machine cluster; all seeds; I deployed schema with replication factor N
- populate the base with WRITE ALL consensus
- now I'm trying to access data with WRITE ANY, and READ ONE.
- I load balance my clients and theoretically I should have a N time better throughput, however that is not the case.

nodetool shows in *Owns* column sum of 100%, instead of N*100% (each node should have all data).

any suggestions?

Comment: sounds a little odd to me.  if you have 100 nodes in your cluster, you're idea is to wait until the data is written and exists on all 100 nodes...?  could be waiting a long time if it's between EC2 Regions / Zones ...

Comment: Thanks for reply. The thing is that I use this setup for some benchmarking, and I populate base only once with the largest N.  After that, I use WRITE ANY and READ ONE on the different subsets of N.
Only first time populating will be time consuming. After I'm trying to see what's happening with my throughput on 1, 2, ...N nodes.

Answer (score 4):

If you increase replicas to N you will not see any throughput benefits, since Cassandra now has to write N copies.  You will also not see any throughput benefits on reads, unless you disable [read repair](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/ReadRepair).

Best practice is to keep replica count constant as you increase N.